# Retrieve user data from Facebook profiles

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

For a research project I want to retrieve user data from Facebook. More specifically, I have about 100 test users, who participated in my survey, and their Facebook names. Now, I want to retrieve several data from their Facebook profiles (birthday, current job, home town,... and much more). As I have a large number of participants, I cannot make each query via the Facebook Graph API manually. I am not very familiar with the Facebook API and programming languages (I only have basic knowledge in Java and R).

So, my question is, what is the easiest way for me to automatically extract the profile data in a database with columns for each attribute of interest? Is it a good idea to write a Facebook App without functionality, but that retrieves the data from all users, who installed the App? Or is it a good idea to use a web-crawler instead?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every user will have to authorized your App if you want to get their data, you can just create an entry page where the user authorizes your App - After authorizing with the required permissions you can store the data in your database.

It may be required to add each user as "Tester" in your App, because most permissions need to get approved by Facebook before they can be used for everyone else. By adding them as Tester, you can avoid the review process. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login - Not sure if Facebook would approved that many permissions just for data retrieval in a research project.

Btw, Scraping/Crawling is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Ok, so a FB-App would be the best solution. Do you know if I can find somewhere an exemplary code to use for the app. So that I only have to specify the data fields I want to retrieve? Do I have to define all the data I want to extract separately or is there a wildcard that I can use to extract all profile information with one command?

Comment: to be honest, if you have no experience with the facebook api, the easiest solution would be to create a website where people could just input their data - without facebook...everyone gets a custom link (yourdomain.com?testerId=123) and you´re good to go.

Comment: that being said, there is "field expansion" to get more data in one call, this page includes example code too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1